# Does a "pruned" i.i.d. multivariate sample behave as the i.i.d. sample?

Tags: covariance, asymptotics, quadratic-form, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ be $n$ points drawn i.i.d. from $\mathbb{C}N_p(0,\Sigma_n)$. The distribution of the covariance $S_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n z_i z_i^*$ is well known in the limit as $n,p(n)\to\infty$ and $n/p\to const$.

What if an adversary removed at each stage in the process (for each value of $n$) one of the $n$ samples (NOTE: not at random)? **Would the limiting distribution of $S_n$ change?**

Generally it seems to me that it should not.

**Second related question**: For each $n$, let $z_a^{(n)}$ be the removed sample point, and let $\tilde S_n$ be the sample covariance of the unremoved samples (without $z_a^{(n)}$). Does the quadratic form $$z_a^{(n)*}\tilde S_n^{-1} z_a^{(n)} $$ behave the same in the limit as $$z_r^*\tilde S_n^{-1} z_r $$,
where $z_r$ is drawn independently from the rest of the samples? In the latter case it should approach the limiting trace of $\Sigma_n$. Does it necessarily do so in the former?

These two questions test my understanding - I want to understand the extent to which "pruning" a set of i.i.d. draws can change the asymptotics. I suspect they shouldn't, but I'm not sure how to show it.

EDIT: I guess these are both hard questions. I'm particularly interested in the answer to the second, but I would accept an answer to the first.